# Can a comparative adjective be used without having anything to compare it to?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

In several languages one can use a construct such as

> I fixed a number of smaller mistakes.

Would this be correct in English, or must I use "I fixed a number of small mistakes" because otherwise it would trigger the question "smaller than *what*?"

Comment: What do you *want* to say? By mentioning the question "smaller than what?", do you mean that you want the answer to this question to be obvious to the listener from context, or do you mean that you want "smaller" to mean exactly the same thing as "small"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's idiomatic, rather than 'technically correct', I'd say.

Though, it could easily be taken to mean...

> "I fixed a number of smaller mistakes, but the really huge errors I just left in there, sorry."

whereas...

> "I fixed a number of small mistakes"

Leaves no ambiguity.
There were only some small mistakes; you fixed them.

By leaving out the comparative, you leave no opportunity for the listener to even unintentionally infer that there **is** a comparison to make.

Comment: What if we write "I fixed a number of **the** smaller mistakes"  - would that carry a distinct sense?

Comment: My brain just naturally looks for the unintended double-meaning in any sentence… & even your modification would still leave me asking "what about the bigger mistakes?" It's not wrong, in any way, it's just open to misinterpretation, accidentally or intentionally.

Answer (score 7):

This is really not a question about grammatical correctness, it's rather an issue of semantics. Grammatically, leaving the second referent of the comparative open is what we call an ellipsis. That makes it a figure of speech, illustrating how the notion of "technical correctness" is really a very relative concept when it comes to practical use of a natural language.

That being said, an elliptic comparative does convey a distinct meaning, i.e. there **is** something to compare to, we're just not mentioning it. Either the not-so-small mistakes have already been fixed, or they're still there. Whatever the case may be, the ellipsis alerts the recipient to consider the broader pragmatic context of the statement.

So I guess my point is that I don't second how the other commenters seem to discourage the use of this type of ambiguity. Ambiguity is a perfectly useful device in a language, one no natural language can do without. Bringing up the question "smaller than *what*?" is the communicative **purpose** of this type of statement, so calling it "wrong" would really deny a very basic function of human language in general.

Comment: +1 for "ellipsis". Although I don't think bringing up the question of "smaller than _what_?" is necessarily intended. Often the omitted part of an elliptic comparative is simply the average/normal/expected value. For example, in "the lion targets the slower members of the herd", the comparative for "slower" is the average member of the herd. Likewise with "smaller mistakes", the implied comparison is either to the set of mistakes actually found in the work, or to the set of "typical" mistakes one is likely to see in such situations, depending on context.